# Projection Formulae

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I learned about projection formulae recently where I was told that sum of projection of two sides of a triangle on the third side is equal to third side. My professor derived the formula using an acute angled triangle and I easily understood that. However when I myself tried to derive the formula using an obtuse angled triangle, I got stuck. When will take projection of longest side and other side on third side , there sum will be more than third side and I also found that that difference of projection of longest side and other side will be equal to third side
[image]

Here sum of projection of AB and AC on BC will be greater than BC but their difference will be equal to BC. Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Things will fall into the right places if the line segments are treated as directed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection formulae:

> (i) a = b cos C + c cos B
> (ii)  b = c cos A + a cos C
> (iii) c = a cos B +  b cos A

From your image:
$$\begin{align}DC &=AC \cos(C)\tag{1}\\
DB &=AB \cos(\pi-B)\\ DB&=-AB \cos(B)\\ -DB &=AB\cos(B)\tag{2}\end{align}$$

(1)+(2),
$$\begin{align}DC-DB &=AC\cos(C)+AB\cos(B)\\ BC &=AC\cos(C)+AB\cos(B)\end{align}$$